# Slow query with join - works fast as individual queries

Tags: mysql, sql, performance, join, query-optimization

I have a sales table with a sales column TCV, customerKey column which holds customerKey stored in customer table. Each row has an order_date and there are other columns irrelevant to this query.

I have to find sales for current period and another period grouped by customers for comparison. So I have this below query.

```
SELECT
  *,
  SUM(TCV) AS sales,
  current_sales - SUM(TCV) AS difference
FROM
  `sales`
  LEFT JOIN
    (SELECT
      customerKey AS customerID,
      SUM(TCV) AS current_sales
    FROM
      `sales`
    WHERE `order_date` BETWEEN '2020-08-01'
      AND '2020-08-31'
    GROUP BY `sales`.`customerKey`) AS `current_sales`
    ON `customerKey` = `customerID`
WHERE `order_date` BETWEEN '2020-09-01'
  AND '2020-09-31'
GROUP BY `sales`.`customerKey`
```

I have this query and it runs very slowly, takes about 30 secs, but if I run the query without the join the result comes back in a second.

What could be the problem, is it structured wrong?

Comment: Tip: NEVER use `SELECT *`

Comment: And 30 days hath September

Comment: `AND ... < '2020-09-01' + INTERVAL 1 MONTH`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rewrite it without join, it will perform better:

```
select s.*
     , current_sales - sales as difference
  from
     ( SELECT customerKey
            , sum(CASE WHEN order_date BETWEEN '2020-08-01' AND '2020-08-31' then TCV else 0 end) current_sales
            , sum(CASE WHEN order_date BETWEEN '2020-09-01' AND '2020-09-30' then TCV else 0 end) sales
         FROM sales
        WHERE order_date BETWEEN '2020-08-01' AND '2020-09-30'
        GROUP 
           BY sales.customerKey
     ) s
```

Comment: @Strawberry Yeah, you are right! In the 2020-09 was 30 days

Comment: As indeed every 09 since the Julian reform (45 BC)

Comment: @Strawberry I put the values in there in a jiffy, they come in dynamically otherwise. So I didn't really pay any heed. But doesn't matter for the date with the issue. :)